# How to save my datagridview with c# winforms bounded to a datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datatable, datagridview

I have bound my MSSQL datatable to a datagridview using the designer (the datatable has atleast 30 columns), it fills the data like this:

```
this.produktaiTableAdapter.Fill(this.veiklosDuomenysDataSet.Produktai);
this.produktaiBindingSource.Filter = advancedDataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText + " = " + Veiklos_ID;
```

It is necessary for me to bind it like this, as I have a lot of code concerning every single column in the DGV (for example, width, currencies, and so on).

Now I want to save all the new, updated, and deleted data in datatagridview to my MSSQL datatable by clicking a Save button. How can I do that? How can I convert my edited datagridview to the datatable?

I also tried this code on my save button click:

```
this.Validate();
this.produktaiBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.produktaiTableAdapter.Update(this.veiklosDuomenysDataSet.Produktai);
```

And.. It doesn't work. I am fairly new with datagridview and datatables overall as this problem I think should have an easy fix.

**EDIT:**

Also, could this line help somehow?

```
DataTable Produktai = advancedDataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
```

**EDIT2:**
This doesn't work either.

```
veiklosDuomenysDataSet.Naudotojai.AcceptChanges();
this.Validate();
this.produktaiBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.produktaiTableAdapter.Update(this.veiklosDuomenysDataSet.Produktai);
MessageBox.Show("Data is saved!");
```

**EDIT3:**

This is a debug picture of my main form: [Here](https://prnt.sc/wjv1ub)

As you can see I have no textbox or buttons like INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE. The user can edit the DGV simply by clicking on a cell and editing the value, add new rows simply by pressing ENTER, deleting the row by clicking Delete (Ištrinti in picture) on the same selected row (NOTE: delete button column is the only unbound column in DGV).

I use MSSQL datatable to bound it with the datagridview, and I want all the rows that are new, deleted or edited in the datagridview to be renewed/updated in the datatable that it is bounded too by save button.

Maybe there should be something different with this information, a wild guess?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". By the way you have downloaded the entire database table into the client and then run a filter on it. This is nearly certainly a worse thing to do than to change (or add) the tableadapter query so that it downloads less data

Comment: No, your edited line doesn't help, or do anything at all, to the tableadapter's ability to save modified rows. Your save code is fine. You don't convert a data grid view to a datatable; when a DGV is bound to a table, editing the data you see in the DGV in the UI will edit the contents of the datatable

Comment: I added 2 rows, 2 columns with data (out of 30, rest is null), click on save button, exit form, refresh dataset, refresh datatable. Result is no new data.

Comment: Is sqlserver using a database that is always attached, or does your program attach the db every time it runs? I don't understand how you can refresh the dataset data if you have exited the form. Do you open a new form?

Comment: No, I meant just recheck the data inserted into datatable. Simply Veiklosduomenys.mdf > Tables > Produktai > (show data) and I click refresh.

Comment: Did you call AcceptChanges anywhere, before you ran your save code?

Comment: I have tried this now:             veiklosDuomenysDataSet.Naudotojai.AcceptChanges();
            this.Validate();
            this.produktaiBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.produktaiTableAdapter.Update(this.veiklosDuomenysDataSet.Produktai);
            MessageBox.Show("Data is saved!"); Result is still the same.

Comment: What you have written is correct, so now we must (because you haven't really posted much code) try and think of all the other things that could be wrong. Pause your code in the debugger before you call tableadapter update and write this in the immediate window: `this.veiklosDuomenysDataSet.Produktai.GetChanges()` - what does it print? (It should be a datatable with some rows if there is anything to save)

Comment: Don't call AcceptChanges. I'm asking questions for things that might be wrong and I just want them answered, I don't want you making assumptions and going off and writing code.. it will make things harder if you're constantly editing the code as an issue is trying to be diagnosed. Remove AcceptChanges again, it is absolutely the wrong thing to do

Comment: Open windows explorer in the root folder of your project. Search the whole folder structure for  `Veiklosduomenys.mdf` - how many databases with this name does your hard disk contain? What are their paths?

Comment: There actually is one copy of the same name in another project I used as a backup. The database file path on the project I am working on so there is no issue in this.

Comment: Some time ago the only time I was succesful in inserting data to datatable is using this method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hCfje5VL-0&ab_channel=codefactory2016 , however it doesn't update the data it inserts new values, and if I click save 2 times it naturally duplicates.

Comment: That because that is an insert statement not an update. Also, coding it that way is bad news.

Comment: Please answer the question as to what you get if you edit the data in the grid then call GetChanges before you call tableadapter.update. You also didn't tell us what the paths were of the MDF files you found.. "it's in the project I'm working on" is not a file path. You're still making assumptions as to why I ask the questions I do, and giving what you think are answers based on what you assume I want to know. Please just answer the questions directly

Comment: Yeah. That video is terrible, don't do it that way

Comment: I am having problems with understanding how to "Pause code" ,"Calling" and "Immediate window", please understand I am still learning these things.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Comment: First of all, the datatable doesn't have any values yet, the first values inserted into it would be the ones from DGV. So I have tried to getchanges, the result was it printed me all the details, the one thing i found concerning this is that when i added 7 rows to the datagrid the immediate window shoed me that the rowcount is actually 7. Does that mean anything?

Comment: By the way this all the code from my form: https://rextester.com/WFSG14529 I understand this is really messy, some lines have no use at all yet. Just for general understanding what mess I've gotten myself into.

Comment: The row count of changed rows should be 7 if you have 7 rows that are all new. Capture the return value of calling Update; it should also be 7. Is it?

Comment: I stopped reading the code, to be honest.. It's really hard to work out what's going on when none of the controls on a form have been renamed, and they're all just the default "label27", "button12" names. Always rename them. Turning variable names into meaningless words is a technique intended to deliberately make code hard to understand (obfuscation) - you should consider refactoring it so it's easier to read.. or even starting over with the minimal set of code needed to demo the problem. Just make a new form and drag one thing out of the data sources window and onto the form

Comment: Yes it is also 7.

Comment: So it's saying that 7 rows have been saved. Post your connection string (probably in the settings of your app)

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Linas\source\repos\IVS\IVS\VeiklosDuomenys.mdf;Integrated Security=True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start over - this will generate a basis for comparison

I didn't encounter any problems saving when I did:

- Make a new project
- Open server explorer, add a connection
- Choose SQLServer file driver, put a path to a new file (new.mdf), click OK, say yes to create it
- Expand the new node in server explorer, right click tables, add a new table with column names that are sensible (just letters and numbers, no spaces, no punctuation or other symbols - you could add percent signs etc and it'll still work, but there's a reason why no-one does it, and that's because it makes life very hard work all down the line. If you think want a column called "Profit %" call it "ProfitPercent" instead). Save the table.
- Open data sources tool panel, add a new datasource, choose database, choose dataset, choose the connectionstring for new.mdf
- **Really carefully read the next question it asks**. Do not just skip past it. If you say Yes then, by default your program will dynamically attach a database that gets erased and replaced every time you run the program (but this is typically what you want). If you say No, then understand that the db your program edits might not be in the project folder at all
- Tixk the table in the wizard, or close the wizard and drag the new table out of **server explorer** into the dataset. Save the dataset
- Open the form, drag the table representation out of the **data sources tool panel** and onto the Form. A datagridview appears
- Run the program, add some rows, click the save button
- Stop the program, run it again - the rows will be there if you said No to the important question earlier. If you said Yes, then stop the program, click the new.mdf file in the Solution Explorer, change "Copy Always" to "Copy if Newer", run the program again. Add rows, save, stop the program and run it again, the rows will be there. The only time they will disappear is if you change the design of the new.mdf database (so that it is newer)

Your form code will now just be something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void myTableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.myTableBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.newDataSet);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'newDataSet.MyTable' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.myTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.newDataSet.MyTable);

    }
}
```

And you won't have written any of it. It's all that's required to load, show, edit and save data using a datagridview. The call to `tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll` is equivalent to `someTableAdapter.Update` - a tableadaptermanager is a convenience device that calls Update in the correct order to ensure that parent rows are created before related child rows

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the posted code in terms of "that's how you save" so the diagnosis needs to methodically chase things through:

- Run the program, load data into the grid, edit some of it
- Pause in the debugger just before you update, and call GetChanges on the datatable that is about to be saved
- If there are no changes, then that table was not edited (the grid is bound to a different table) or no edits were made (the grid edit was cancelled not committed) or the edit's were reverted or accepted (RejectChanges or AcceptChanges was called on the datatable)
- if there are changes move to capturing the return value from tableadapter update (Write `var x = tableadapter.update(..)`) and step the debugger over the call to update
- if the result is 0 then no rows were updated; this should result in a concurrencyexception if there were changes and the tableadapter query is enabled for concurrency (probably the default). If your tableadapter doesn't have an update query built in then again you should get an exception if you try to save edits ("update requires a valid updateconmand when passed a collection with modified rows". If it's just 0 and no exception is thrown then for some reason no rows were updated - not a situation I'd expect and would need some more investigation
- if the result is > 0 then an update was made (changes were saved). On a tableadapter the Update method is responsible for all inserts, updates and deletes. If you can't see your changes it you're most likely looking in the wrong database file, or your build process is erasing your file and replacing it with a new one. This most often happens with file based databases like Access but can happen with sql server if your database file is being dynamically attached and detached

Comment: Can you check EDIT3, probably I started the question bad in the first place. I will now proceed to digest your answer.

Comment: The result is 0, but I think the problem is with my datatable column values, they are not how data property names should be. For example: this is from my immediate window,     _Akcija___Column: {Akcija, %}
    _Antkainis___Column: {Antkainis, %}
    _Galutinė_kaina__EURColumn: {Galutinė kaina, EUR}

Comment: The result is still 0, there is no exception.

Comment: Have you named your database columns `Akcija, %` and `Antkainis, %`? I doubt it will cause a problem (you can see that the code is coping with the commas, spaces and percent signs by replacing them with underscores) but using column names like that is a fast way to a headache. Rename them so they use only NamesLikeThis - no spaces, no punctuation, no percent symbols or other characters that mean something in SQL

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the result is 0" when before you said "the result is 7"

Comment: Getchanges in the immediate window displays count = 7 (if i exactly added 7 rows to the datagrid), but when I call update test1 result is 0; var test1 = this.produktaiTableAdapter.Update(this.veiklosDuomenysDataSet.Produktai);

Comment: So that means I definetly fall to the (if the result is 0 then no rows were updated) category. Well, atleast we now know that there is a problem with updating with tableadapter. The tableadapter I checked has a update query.

Comment: And it's definitely veiklosDuomenysDataSet.Produktai that you called getchanges on? If you call it again after you Update do you get the same 7 rows?

Comment: Don't go too far down the rabbit hole of update queries in the tableadapter; you're claiming you addded 7 rows to the grid, so it is the INSERT query in the adapter that you need to examine to find out why it doesn't insert new rows, not the update query. Ignore the fact that the method name is Update(); it inserts too and you claim your rows are new, not edited, so you need to investigate why they don't insert (but tbh, I find it quite difficult to understand how an insert query can return 0 rows inserted, not transactions/rollbacks, and no exceptions)